# Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter

Tags: xcode, admob

i a having issue with rewarded videos in admob , when i use test unit ID its worked but when i use real unit id i got this error :

```
[ADMOB][ADS][LANDING] Reward based video ad failed to load. Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}
2018-05-12 12:08:14.070913+0300 [2284:565044] <Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
```

any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

its not a problem , since its return error "no ads to show" means there is no ads to show in my country or region , so i've used a VPN to change my location and the ads start showing .